# How to continue reading a txt file after getting exception in python

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to execute the SQL commands written in text file through python script. But in case any SQL command fails python script throws the error and stop executing the text file in between. And the result is few of the commands are executed and few are left.

I am expecting my code to throw the error and continue executing rest of the commands in the text file.

**My code for reading :**

```
import sqlite3 as sqlite
File_Name = input(" please provide text file name : ")
DB_Name = input (" Please provide the Database Name : ")
connection = sqlite.connect(DB_Name)
cursor = connection.cursor()

Text_File = open (File_Name,'r')
Text = Text_File.read()
Text_File.close()
try:
    cursor.executescript(Text)
except sqlite.Error as e:
    print ("sql command error  ",e)
connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

**Text file is like :**

```
drop table test_p;
drop table test_p1;
drop table test_p2;

create table test_p(a number );
create table test_p1(a number );
create table test_p2(a number );

insert into test_p values(1);
insert into test_p values(2);
insert into test_p1 values(3);
insert into test_p1 values(4);
insert into test_p2 values(5);
insert into test_p2 values(6);
```

Here if table test_p1 is not existing and i am running the script then test_p will be dropped and exception is thrown .

Comment: Why not just use `DROP TABLE ... IF EXISTS` then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read and execute the lines in your file 1 by 1:

```
for line in open(File_Name,'r'):
    try:
        cursor.executescript(line)
    except sqlite.Error as e:
        print ("sql command error  ", e)
```

Comment: It is somewhat of an overkill to use `executescript` on a single line. The code is more readable (as it expresses the actual operation better) if you use just `execute`instead.

Comment: Further, you should probably use `with` in conjunction with opening the file, or at least close it after the `for` loop. (You might knoiw this, but someone else reading here might miss it.)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comment, for the particular error, it is possible to avoid it by using `IF EXISTS`. In the general case, you could loop your input and use `execute` on each line instead of `executescript`:

```
import sqlite3 as sqlite
File_Name = input(" please provide text file name : ")
DB_Name = input (" Please provide the Database Name : ")
connection = sqlite.connect(DB_Name)
cursor = connection.cursor()

with open (File_Name,'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        try:
            cursor.execute(line)
        except sqlite.Error as e:
            print ("sql command error  ",e)

connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

This will lead each offending line to report an error, but then continnue execution on the next line.